# Func delegate doesn't chain methods

Tags: c#, delegates, func

Lets imagine simple delegate calls:

```
void Main()
{
    Func<int, int, string> tfunc = null;
    tfunc += Add; // bind first method
    tfunc += Sub; // bind second method 

    Console.WriteLine(tfunc(2, 2));
}

private string Add(int a, int b)
{
    return "Add: " + (a + b).ToString();
}

private string Sub(int a, int b)
{
    return "Sub: " + (a - b).ToString();
}
```

The result of this program is:

```
Sub: 0
```

So, why **Add** method was not called? I'm expecting to call Method Add, and **then** method Sub.

Comment: When calling a delegate that has a return value, only the last executed delegate returns a value to the invoking code. In this case, `Add` which is called first has its return value thrown away by the `Sub` delegate which executes afterward.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Add** was correctly chained and called, take a look at the result of

```
void Main()
{
    Func<int, int, string> tfunc = null;
    tfunc += Add; // bind first method
    tfunc += Sub; // bind second method 

    Console.WriteLine(tfunc(2, 2));
}

private string Add(int a, int b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inside Add");
    return "Add: " + (a + b).ToString();
}

private string Sub(int a, int b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inside Sub");
    return "Sub: " + (a - b).ToString();
}
```

It is:

```
Inside Add
Inside Sub
Sub: 0
```

What is not chained, because there is no way to access it, is the result of the Add method. Delegates that return a value, in case of chaining, return the value of the last method invoked, that is the last method that was added to the delegate.

This is specified in part 15.4 of the [C# 4.0 language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

> Invocation of a delegate instance whose invocation list contains
>   multiple entries proceeds by invoking each of the methods in the
>   invocation list, synchronously, in order. ...
>   If the delegate invocation includes output parameters or a
>   return value, their final value will come from the invocation of the
>   last delegate in the list.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the return value is not passed between the method invocations, so the output only captures the last string returned. I.e. the return of Add is lost.